# How can i iterate though this list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tuples

I have a regexp which returns a list like this `[('2', '2', '0')]`. How can i iterate through each item in the above mentioned list?

```
>>> for i in k:
...     print i
...
('2', '2', '0')
```

when tried to access the element in the list, we have to access this way

```
>>> k[0][0]
'2'
>>>
```

*Additional question from comment:*
How can i validate each element in that tuple? I tried this:

```
for i in k:
  print i
  for j in i:
    if j == 2:
      print 'yes'
    else:
      print 'no'
```

Comment: Your regexp returns a list containing a tuple with 3 elements, so yes you have to do `k[0][0], k[0][1], k[0][2]`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you want to do:

```
for i in k[0]:
```

This says loop over the elements in the first element of `k`, which in this case is a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). e.g.

```
>>> k = [('2', '2', '0')]
>>> for i in k[0]:
...   print(i)
...
2
2
0
```

If you're getting a list of tuples back from a regex operation, I assume you're calling [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html#re.findall).  Remember that you may get back a list of more than one tuple (if multiple parts of the string match your regex).  This may not be possible, for instance if your pattern can only match the beginning (`^`) or end (`$`) of the string, however it's worth being aware that your list could be more than one element long, in which case you need to iterate over both the inner and outer list.  Consider:

```
>>> k = [('2', '2', '0'), ('3', '3', '1')]
>>> for i in k[0]:
...   print(i)
...
2
2
0
```

With this we've lost the second element.  If you can't be sure your list will always be one element long, you'll need an inner loop, like so:

```
>>> for i in k:
...   print(i)
...   for j in i:
...     print(j)
...
('2', '2', '0')
2
2
0
('3', '3', '1')
3
3
1
```

This gives us access to every tuple (as `i`) as well as every element of each tuple (as `j`).  Your exact use case will decide what of the above you need, but these are all the basic options.

---

> How can i validate each element in that tuple?

It sounds like by "validate" you mean "is the value 2".  Note that the tuple contains sub-*strings* of the string you're matching, but the conditional in your sample, `if j == 2:`, is checking that `j` is the *numeral* `2`.  You can either change it to `if j == '2':` (note the quotes) or cast it to an integer with `if int(j) == 2:`.

```
for i in k:
  for j in i:
    print('yes' if j == '2' else 'no')
```

Comment: How can i validate each element in that Tuple. I tried this ,

    for i in k:
        print i
    for j in i:
        if j == 2:
            print 'yes'
        else:
            print 'no'

Comment: @user3363550 I edited your question to include the code you pasted in the comment.  In general, please avoid asking new questions in comments; either update your question, or even better post a new one.  I've updated my answer to address your additional question.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over all matches and all values of each match by doing:

```
for match in [('2', '2', '0')]:
    print match
    for value in match:
        print value
```

And, as you mentioned, you can use `match[0]` to access a particular value of a match.

Answer (score 0):

It's a list with only one element (a tuple). Try like this:

```
for x in k[0]:
    print x
```

You're asking to loop through the first element of the list, a tuple with three elements.

To answer your question in the comments, you're list contains all strings.

```
for x in k[0]:
    if x == '2':
        print 'yes'
    else:
        print 'sorry'
```

This will print out

```
yes
yes
sorry
```

Comment: Well, your list has strings in it, not integers. Try this, for x in k[0]: if x=='2': print 'yes' else: print 'sorry'

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp looks like it returns a list where each element is a tuple. You have one element, a tuple of length three, so the loop would be:

```
for i in k[0]:
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of tuples and in your case it only has a single element.

Assuming you have more than 1 tuple to loop through, you want something like this:

```
>>> k = [('2', '2', '0')]
>>> for i in k:
...     for j in i:
...         print j
...
2
2
0
```

However, if you are sticking with just needing the first element, you can eliminate the inner loop:

```
>>> for i in k[0]:
...    print i
2
2
0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it for other than printing, you should make a list and then access it as you need:

```
list = []
for x in k:
    list.extend(y for y in x)
```

This covers all the cases that have been answered, and gives you a list to work on.